# wincache ucache gets cleared while ttl is set to 0

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, memcached

I have wincache running on IIS7 with the following in my PHP.ini

```
wincache.ucachesize = "80"
wincache.ttlmax = "0"
wincache.fcenabled = "0"
```

I use the ucache to store some heavy data, gathered from the Database.

For example:

```
    Array
    (
        [memory_total] => 83886080
        [memory_free] => 57166036
        [num_used_blks] => 85188
        [num_free_blks] => 1
        [memory_overhead] => 1363056
    )
```

And some sample items:

```
  [ucache_entries] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key_name] => ***edited***
                    [value_type] => array
                    [value_size] => 68214
                    [ttl_seconds] => 0
                    [age_seconds] => 126
                    [hitcount] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key_name] => ***edited***
                    [value_type] => array
                    [value_size] => 88
                    [ttl_seconds] => 0
                    [age_seconds] => 354
                    [hitcount] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key_name] => ***edited***
                    [value_type] => array
                    [value_size] => 833553
                    [ttl_seconds] => 0
                    [age_seconds] => 122
                    [hitcount] => 1
                )
```

Now, the problem is that when I do not use the application for a while (sometimes like 30 mintues?) The cache is totally cleared. This is while I have set the ttl="0". According to the PHP website:

> wincache.ttlmax integer: 
>       Defines the maximum time to live (in seconds) for a cached entry without being used.         Setting it to 0 will disable the cache scavenger, so the cached entries will never be removed from the cache during the lifetime of the IIS worker process.

I cannot find anything special in the IIS logging, I also have no clue how to debug this. Anyone got some answers or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution but from what I've read FastCGI on IIS kills the instance after some idle time and the usercache goes with it.  IIS can be configured as a workaround but I bet a better solution exists.

Comment: Sorry, late reaction but you are right. I simply do not understand why Wincache is such volatile for a caching..

Answer (score 0):

If your hosted solution is not getting traffic every 10 minutes or so, there are two key components where you will need to update the default configuration.

**App Recycling:**

By default, the application pools in IIS will have an idle timeout set to 20 minutes. So, if no one hits the server for 20 minutes, the app pool will be terminated with the user cache and then recreated on the next visitor. Additionally, there is a default recycle every 29 hours that will also clear the user cache. To resolve, set the idle timeout to 0, and set a specific time for the app pool to recycle, which will effectively act as a daily (or whatever frequency) process to intentionally clear the user cache. Here is an article with screenshots:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes

**PHP FastCGI idleTimeout:**

You'll also need to change the global FastCGI Settings for your php-cgi.  IIS Manager->Server->FastCGI Settings.  Edit the php-cgi that you are using and set the idle timeout (I set mine to 24 hours or 86400s).